# Not able to run update query using HQL in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to run update query using HQL. I feel that I'm missing something in the query. Because Insert query is working fine. My HQL Query is

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update school set dbvalue = :dbvalue" +
                    " where nameValue= :nameValue and uid = :uid");
            query.setParameter("dbvalue", dashBoardValue);
            query.setParameter("nameValue ", nameValue );
            query.setParameter("uid", userId);

            int rowsAffected = query.executeUpdate();
```

The error which I'm getting is

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: school is not mapped [update school set dbvalue = :dbvalue where nameValue = :nameValue and uid = :uid]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intu</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<mapping class="com.cni.school" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Is there anything needs to be added?

Comment: @NallaSrinivas school

Comment: please, wirte School(Java Class Name or Bean ) whose .hbm.xml or Annotated class.

Comment: can you edit Question and add School class which you have mapped with Database ?

Comment: please, add .hbm.xml OR annotated java class not cfg.xml

Comment: @Syed In java we should n`t define Class with small letters So, first rename your class as School instead of school and then map this class with database table

Comment: Thanks Guys. Got it. :)

Comment: `setParameter("nameValue ",` also looks strange with an extraneous space.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, adjusted. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen JPQL, or perhaps HQL here, insist on having the case of the entity match the case in the statement. Try `School`.

EDIT: This is what (at least version 4.3) the Hibernate Documentation says on [Case Sensitivity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-casesensitivity).

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. But what exactly is the diff? Should it be entity name as it is?

Comment: Yes, HQL is case sensitive as to the Entity.

Comment: Hi Nicholas. If its possible for you to check on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546458/hibernate-service-unknown-exception-getting-in-my-java

Answer (score 0):

Try committing the changes after executing the query.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

   //your query execution...

tx.commit();
session.close();
```