# Hibernate Service unknown exception getting in my java

Tags: java, hibernate, session

After hitting the server for few times, I'm getting Hibernate service unknown exception. I feel that its due to session factory or session issue. Is there anything needs to be updated in the following code? Am I using the session or session factory in the correct manner?

```
public class SchoolImpl implements School {

    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    @Override
    public String addSchoolDetails(String userId, String keyName, String dashBoardValue) {

        boolean status = false;
        String result = "failure";

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            // Code goes here 
            insertOrUpdateSchoolDetails('bla','bla','bla','bla')

        } catch(HibernateException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //session.close();
        }
        return result; 
    }

    public boolean insertOrUpdateSchoolDetails(String userId, String keyName,
        String dashBoardValue, String typeOfOp) {
        boolean result = false;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Integer uID = null;
        if(typeOfOp.equals("insert")) {
        System.out.println("About to insert a new record for User :"+userId); 
            try {
                //Code
                tx.commit();
                System.out.println("Successfully inserted the record");

            } catch(HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null)
                    tx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                session.close();
                factory.close();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("About to update the existing record for User :"+userId);
            try {
                //Code
                tx.commit();
                if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Updated " + rowsAffected + " rows.");
                }               
            } catch(HibernateException e) {
                if (tx != null)
                    tx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                session.close();
                factory.close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Hibernate cfg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intu</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.cni.School" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The error which is showing is

```
 SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested  [org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory]
at   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.getRegionFactory(Settings.java:300)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1322)
```

Comment: Posting you hibernate configuration file will help. Are you using any second level cache? Looks like you are setting `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` property to `org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory`. If you are not using second level cache remove this property or set it with a correct implementation.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, posted the config file too. Please check it

Comment: One possible reason could be `factory.close();`. You can remove that any try. But more important, I know you are new to Hibernate,I would suggest going through some hibernate examples to understand and use it better. For ex: closing sessionFactory is not needed for every operation, to update/insert you may try if `merge` is a better option, starting the transaction twice is not needed etc. May be you can start with [link](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate)

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, from where should I remove? They are actually placed in two places and in "addSchoolDetails", I'm started a session.beginTransaction().. Should I close session there also?

Comment: Since you mentioned `hitting the server ` I presume it is deployed in some web/app server. I am referring to `sessionFactory` close i.e., `factory.close` and not the `session`. That needs to be removed, wherever it is. On a different note, I assume you are creating a new instance of `SchoolImpl` every time. If not move the `session` creation logic `factory.openSession` into one of the methods, may be `insertOrUpdate...` method. But then, I highly recommend, going thru some some hibernate tutorials.

Comment: Server in the sense, the local tomcat server. Ok. thx @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu